# How do I keep an onInput event from being triggered when using document.execCommand()?

Tags: javascript, input, contenteditable, execcommand

I have a `div` whose contents the user can edit via the `contenteditable` attribute. When the user types something in the div, a function is called. I am using the `oninput` event to trigger that function, since `onkeydown` doesn't work with some of the stuff the function is supposed to do.

I also have bold, italic, and underline buttons that allow the user to style the text accordingly, via `document.execCommand()`.

**My problem:** The function triggered oninput should not be triggered when the user uses the buttons to style the text. But that is what is happening. Is there any way I can prevent it?

Here's my code:

**Note:** For this example, I simplified the function triggered oninput. In reality, it will do a lot more than just changing the `innerHTML` of an element.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7L821dma/)

```js
document.getElementById("editableDiv").focus();

function boldText () {
    document.execCommand("bold");
}

function myFunction () {
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML="The content was changed."
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

input {
  padding: 5px;
  outline: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Bold" onclick="boldText();">

<div id="editableDiv" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" oninput="myFunction();">
  Hello, World!
</div>

<p id="feedback"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an If Statement to the function, making it only work if `event.inputType != "formatBold"`:

```js
function myFunction() {
  if (event.inputType == "formatBold") {
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "The text was stylized.";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "The content was changed.";
    // + other things the function is supposed to do.
  }
}
```